# chmod CommandNotFoundException when building docker image on windows machine

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile, sh, chmod

We are trying to build a `Python-flask` image on `Windows 10` machine and here are the commands that are part of Dockerfile.

```
RUN chmod +x /var/www/projectname/entrypoint.local.sh
```

We are getting an error while trying to build the image using docker file

**Here is the error:**

```
chmod : The term 'chmod' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,  script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path  was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:76
+ ... nce = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; chmod +x /var ...
+                                                             ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (chmod:String) [], ParentContain     sErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException   ERROR: Service 'controller_service' failed to build: The command 'powershell
-Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; chmod +x /var/www/projectname/entry point.local.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

It is considering **chmod** which is in `Dockerfile` as `Windows` command.

**Edit1:**

I'm trying to build the image as part of `docker-compose` using the below command:

`docker-compose up --build`.

I'm running the above command in `Terminal` in `Pycharm` in `Windows`.

Please suggest any fix for this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to build the `Linux` images when you've actually configured your `Docker desktop` to build `Windows images`.

That's the reason you might be getting the error `chmod` command not found which is specific to `Linux` and won't work on `Windows`.

You can follow these steps to resolve it.

1. Go to the Docker desktop icon on the bottom right corner on in task bar.
2. Right click and click on option to `Switch to Linux containers`.
3. Try to build the images now.

You should be good to go.